# How to evaluate tuples in parallel using rpar Strategy in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I stumbled upon a problem with `Eval` monad and `rpar` `Strategy` in Haskell. Consider following code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies

main :: IO ()
main = print . sum . inParallel2 $ [1..10000]

inParallel :: [Double] -> [Double]
inParallel xss = runEval . go $ xss
    where
      go []  = return []
      go (x:xs) = do
        x'  <- rpar $ x + 1
        xs' <- go xs
        return (x':xs')

inParallel2 :: [Double] -> [Double]
inParallel2 xss = runEval . go $ xss
    where
      go []  = return []
      go [x] = return $ [x + 1]
      go (x:y:xs) = do
        (x',y') <- rpar $ (x + 1, y + 1)
        xs'     <- go xs
        return (x':y':xs'
```

I compile and run it like this:

```
ghc -O2 -Wall -threaded -rtsopts -fforce-recomp -eventlog eval.hs
./eval +RTS -N3 -ls -s
```

When I use `inParallel` function parallelism works as expected. In the output runtime statistics I see:

```
SPARKS: 100000 (100000 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)
```

When I switch to `inParallel2` function all parallelism is gone:

```
SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)
```

Why doesn't evaluation of tuples work in parallel? I tried forcing the tuple before passing it to rpar:

```
rpar $!! (x + 1, y + 1)
```

but still no result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `rpar` strategy annotates a term for possible evaluation in parallel, but only up to **weak head normal form**, which essentially means, up to the outermost constructor. So for an integer or double, that means full evaluation, but for a pair, only the pair constructor, not its components, will get evaluated.

Forcing the pair before passing it to `rpar` is not going to help. Now you're evaluating the pair locally, before annotating the already evaluated tuple for possible parallel evaluation.

You probably want to combine the `rpar` with the `rdeepseq` strategy, thereby stating that the term should be completely evaluated, if possible in parallel. You can do this by saying

```
(rpar `dot` rdeepseq) (x + 1, y + 1)
```

The `dot` operator is for composing strategies.

There is, however, yet another problem with your code: pattern matching forces immediate evaluation, and therefore using pattern matching for `rpar`-annotated expressions is usually a bad idea. In particular, the line

```
(x',y') <- (rpar `dot` rdeepseq) (x + 1, y + 1)
```

will defeat all parallelism, because before the spark can be picked up for evaluation by another thread, the local thread will already start evaluating it in order to match the pattern. You can prevent this by using a lazy / irrefutable pattern:

```
~(x',y') <- (rpar `dot` rdeepseq) (x + 1, y + 1)
```

Or alternatively use `fst` and `snd` to access the components of the pair.

Finally, don't expect actual speedup if you create sparks that are as cheap as adding one to an integer. While sparks themselves are relatively cheap, they are not cost-free, so they work better if the computation you are annotating for parallel evaluation is somewhat costly.

You might want to read some tutorials on using strategies, such as Simon Marlow's
[Parallel and Concurrent Programming using Haskell](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/par-tutorial-cefp-2012.pdf) or my own [Deterministic Parallel Programming in Haskell](http://www.well-typed.com/Hal6/Presentation.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! This problem actually arose when I was reading Marlow's tutorial and doing some exercises of my own. Adding 1 is only an example, I didn't want to complicate sample code with some elaborate computations.